# Convert list of strings of delimited values to list of lists of floats

Tags: python, list-comprehension, string-conversion

I have this array of strings of comma-separated numbers:

```py
data = ['1,14.23,1.71,2.43,15.6,127,2.8,3.06,.28,2.29,5.64,1.04,3.92,1065',
        '1,13.2,1.78,2.14,11.2,100,2.65,2.76,.26,1.28,4.38,1.05,3.4,1050',
        '1,13.16,2.36,2.67,18.6,101,2.8,3.24,.3,2.81,5.68,1.03,3.17,1185',
        '1,14.37,1.95,2.5,16.8,113,3.85,3.49,.24,2.18,7.8,.86,3.45,1480',
        '1,13.24,2.59,2.87,21,118,2.8,2.69,.39,1.82,4.32,1.04,2.93,735',
        '1,14.2,1.76,2.45,15.2,112,3.27,3.39,.34,1.97,6.75,1.05,2.85,1450']
```

I want to transform the list of strings of comma-separated numbers to a list of lists of floats, so that the result will look like this:

```py
[
 [1, 14.23, 1.71, 2.43, 15.6, 127, 2.8, 3.06, 0.28, 2.29, 5.64, 1.04, 3.92, 1065],
 [1, 13.2, 1.78, 2.14, 11.2, 100, 2.65, 2.76, 0.26, 1.28, 4.38, 1.05, 3.4, 1050],
 [1, 13.16, 2.36, 2.67, 18.6, 101, 2.8, 3.24, 0.3, 2.81, 5.68, 1.03, 3.17, 1185],
 [1, 14.37, 1.95, 2.5, 16.8, 113, 3.85, 3.49, 0.24, 2.18, 7.8, 0.86, 3.45, 1480],
 [1, 13.24, 2.59, 2.87, 21, 118, 2.8, 2.69, 0.39, 1.82, 4.32, 1.04, 2.93, 735],
 [1, 14.2, 1.76, 2.45, 15.2, 112, 3.27, 3.39, 0.34, 1.97, 6.75, 1.05, 2.85, 1450]
]
```

How can I do this using one or more list comprehensions (or nested loops, if this task is impossible using list comprehensions)? I am looking for an answer that doesn't need any external libraries (e.g. `numpy`, `pandas`, etc.).

Comment: You can do it with nested list comprehensions. The inner list comprehension converts the string to a list of floats. The outer list comprehension processes each string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```py
nested = [[float(y) for y in x.split(',')] for x in data]
print(nested)
```

Result:

```
[[1.0, 14.23, 1.71, 2.43, 15.6, 127.0, 2.8, 3.06, 0.28, 2.29, 5.64, 1.04, 3.92, 1065.0], [1.0, 13.2, 1.78, 2.14, 11.2, 100.0, 2.65, 2.76, 0.26, 1.28, 4.38, 1.05, 3.4, 1050.0], [1.0, 13.16, 2.36, 2.67, 18.6, 101.0, 2.8, 3.24, 0.3, 2.81, 5.68, 1.03, 3.17, 1185.0], [1.0, 14.37, 1.95, 2.5, 16.8, 113.0, 3.85, 3.49, 0.24, 2.18, 7.8, 0.86, 3.45, 1480.0], [1.0, 13.24, 2.59, 2.87, 21.0, 118.0, 2.8, 2.69, 0.39, 1.82, 4.32, 1.04, 2.93, 735.0], [1.0, 14.2, 1.76, 2.45, 15.2, 112.0, 3.27, 3.39, 0.34, 1.97, 6.75, 1.05, 2.85, 1450.0]]
```

Atlernatively, you can use `map()`:

```py
nested = [list(map(float, x.split(','))) for x in data]
```